# jQuery Image Rotator Not Working

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with my first attempt at jQuery and an image rotator. I've been trying for hours/days to check the code, but I can't find the problem. I followed a tutorial on Lynda.com and have rechecked the code three times. Maybe it has something to do with not downloading jQuery properly or not noting the file properly in the html? Or, is the problem something else?

Here is the URL with the html and javascript code: http://www.planetvisioncreation.com/culturalpublishingservice.html

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!
Vicki

Comment: Make sure that Jquery file is in that directory. And put it inside the $(document).ready(function(){ //here your code }) http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized

Answer (score 0):

Your `marquee_includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js` file is saved in an incorrect character encoding, I suggest you simply download the correct file from jquery.com, not mess with it and upload on your server as is. If that still doesn't help, your file transfer program may be transcoding files to different encodings.

An even easier way would be to include [Google-hosted jQuery](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) in your page.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting closer. The Google script helped. Now, the last image is cycling through 3 of the 12 photos, but the first three aren't doing anything. Why would that be?